# It seems that the limit function is "cherry-picking" as values approach $0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, definition

A rule that I've been taught over and over is that dividing by zero gives an undefined value. Another fact is that multiplying by zero, equals zero. Also, zero is nothing. Now, when I'm learning calculus, it seems that the limit function only cares about the fact that "zero = nothing", but pays no attention to the other rules, allowing one to, without consequence, let a value approach zero, so as to remove certain terms.

Here's a few concrete examples:

$$\lim_{b \rightarrow a}\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}$$

That this would amount to anything, when applying arithmetic or algebraic thinking, is crazy. First of all, as $b$ approaches $a$, the numerator and denominator approaches $0$, no? What calculus does here only looks like trickery to me, and not rigor; let's say $f(x) = x^2$.

$$\frac{b^2 - a^2}{b-a} = b + a$$

I agree with this, it's simple algebra. Now, after procuring this expression, calculus says the answer is simply $2a$ as $b$ approaches $a$. That's disregarding the fact that having $b = a$ changes what the fraction equals; algebraically, it would go from $b + a$ to UNDEF. However, calculus isn't simply substituting $b$ for $a$, it's letting $b$ **approach** $a$. That's different, but I don't see how that difference allows us to say the limit of the fraction is $2a$, and not UNDEF. To put it simply:

1. The logical conclusion of $b + a$ as $b \rightarrow a$ is $2a$
2. The logical conclusion of $\displaystyle \frac{x}{b-a}$ as $b \rightarrow a$ is UNDEF.

The above difference quotient happens to be both $(1)$ and $(2)$, yet calculus choses $(1)$, which is understandable, as it produces more helpful answers; but I don't know how to accept it. Why is this okay? I mean, just because something is helpful, doesn't mean it's true. In math, we define based on convenience, but here, we're not talking about simply defining something; we're evaluating the result of an already defined expression. The only thing that is defined by calculus is the limit function, which makes me think that the answer lies in how it works. I just can't see that answer.

Another example, just for good measure:

$$f(x) = x^2$$

$$(x + \Delta x)^2 = x^2 + 2x\Delta x + (\Delta x)^2$$

Brilliant.org's course says: "When $\Delta x$ is **very** small, the area of that smaller shaded piece, $(\Delta x)^2$, is so tiny that we can ignore it completely."

And that's fine, because the course goes on to use $\approx$, and not $=$. So, by ignoring the little piece, we get this:

$$(x + \Delta x)^2 \approx x^2 + 2x\Delta x$$

No problems here. Now, let's figure out the rate of change for the square: we take the difference in area and divide it by the difference in side length, $\Delta x$, which is just the rise over run.

$$(x + \Delta x)^2 - x^2 \approx \frac{2x\Delta x}{\Delta x}$$

Still, I have no problems. It is clear that at this point, one could cancel out the two $\Delta x$'s, and be left with the approximate answer, $2x$. What is not clear, is that this goes from approximate, to exact, when $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$:

$$2x\times 0 = 0, \ \ \frac{2x\times 0}{0} = \text{UNDEF}$$

As said, this feels like trickery. We rearrange the expression, so that the factors of $0$ are "out of sight, out of mind", and then we get our answer. The original expression and the rearranged expression are equal, so if the original expression ends up with issues like "UNDEF due to $\div 0$", then the rearranged expression should suffer the same consequences, no?

Comment: Concerns such as these were expressed by George Berkeley in the 18th century and ultimately lead to the invention of the theory of limits.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus, In Berkeley's time, were they using infinitesimals, or something else?

Comment: "That this would amount to anything, when applying arithmetic or algebraic thinking, is crazy." Bishop Berkeley had the same objection. He called Newton's limit of the difference quotient, "the ghosts of departed quantities." If these guys came back today they'd get on the Internet and flame with the best of 'em. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Analyst

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your concerns are very reasonable from the perspective of someone learning calculus for the first time, but do not actually pose a real problem. There are no arbitrary choices being made for reasons of convenience. I think a similar complaint could be lodged on against much of the modern theory of quantum field theories, where proper mathematical foundations have often not been worked out yet, and so choices have to be made while computing on the basis of what turns out a well defined answer. I hope I can can convince you that this is not the situation in modern calculus.

Suppose we have have an expression like $a+b$ and wish to take the limit $\lim_{b\to a}b+a.$ For this specific limit it is valid to apply a rule where we replace all occurrences of $b$ by $a$ and so get $2a.$ This step is valid in this context because, for fixed values of $a$, the function $b+a$ is continuous in the variable $b$. In fact, whenever a function $f(b)$ is continuous, it is valid to apply the rule
$$
\lim_{b\to a} f(b)=f(a).
$$

Now let's look at the second context where you are trying to apply this rule. This is in the evaluation of the limit
$$
\lim_{b\to a}\frac{b^2-a^2}{b-a}.
$$
Of course it does not make sense in this context to evaluate the expression at $b=a$ and get $\frac{0}{0}.$ But the deeper reason that replacing $b$ by $a$ to evaluate the limit is not valid in this context is that, for fixed $a$, the function $\frac{b^2-a^2}{b-a}$ is not continuous at $b=a$. In fact, it cannot be continuous at this point because the function $f(b)=\frac{b^2-a^2}{b-a}$ is not even defined at $b=a$! A function $f(b)$ can only be continuous at values of $b$ for which $f$ is defined. This might seem like a tricky way of saying that we just don't get a convenient result when $b=a$, but it is actually the fact that we are attempting to apply a rigorous theorem (we can replace $b$ by $a$ whenever the function is continuous) outside the context where that theorem is actually valid.

About your claim that $\lim_{b\to a}\frac{x}{b-a}$ is undefined, this actually depends on whether and how $b$ occurs in the expression $x$. If $x$ in no way depends on $b$ and so is fixed relative to change in $b$, then your claim is correct. However, if the expression represented by $x$ depends on $b$ then the limit $\lim_{b\to a}\frac{x}{b-a}$ may actually be well defined.

Comment: [1/2] "(...) but it is actually the fact that we are attempting to apply a rigorous theorem (we can replace b by a whenever the function is continuous) outside the context where that theorem is actually valid." I was expecting you to follow this up with something, because as it stands, it seems you are arguing for the view that limits are nonsensical (which isn't the case). You say that substituting the approaching value with the limit value within the expression is valid when dealing with continuous functions; that makes sense. Then you say that for non-continuous functions, this is invalid.

Comment: [2/2] Again, I agree that this doesn't work with non-continuous functions, because you wind up with undefined values. However, with my given understanding, that just means the limit function cannot be applied to these non-continuous functions. So, I was kind of expecting that you'd explain what kind of way we're able to apply this method outside of the context it's valid. How can we look at the limit of a function that has a value approach another value that in the process, takes the function out of its continuous domain?

Comment: @user110391 I am not sure what gave you the impression the I am arguing limits are nonsensical. Applying the theorem with non-continuous functions does not necessarily produce undefined values, it may just produce incorrect values. Outside the context where the function $f$ is continuous, you cannot necessarily apply this method. It can still be applied in certain situations, for example, when $b\neq a$ we have $\frac{b^2-a^2}{b-a}=b+a,$ and then of course $b+a$ is continuous in $b$, allowing us to apply the theorem $\lim_{b\to a}f(b)=f(a).$

Comment: @user110391 However, it is not always possible to evaluate a limit in this way. You seem to have the misconception that substituting $b$ by $a$ is actually how limits are defined. This is not the case. The rigorous definition of limit is a bit complex, but see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function.

Comment: @user1103911 No, that is not correct. The value of $\lim_{b\to a} f(b)$ actually does not depend on $f(a)$ or even whether $f(a)$ is defined. It only depends on on $f(b)$ in a neighborhood of $a$ when $b\neq a.$ I am assuming you meant $\lim_{b\to a} f(b),$ not $\lim_{b\to a}f(a).$

Comment: I see that $b + a$ is continuous over $b$, and thus can be used. Thing is, the function for the secant line's slope is $\frac{b^2 -a^2}{b-a}$, which isn't continuous. It so happens that $\frac{b^2 -a^2}{b-a} = b+a \implies a \neq b$, which is why we can switch the difference ratio out for the simpler $b+a$. But that this replacement is founded on the very fact that the difference ratio equals $b+a$... but it only equals it when $a \neq b$. Also, is this correct: A limit, $\lim_{b \rightarrow a} f(a)$ is definable $\iff f(b) \neq$ UNDEF $\lor (f(a \neq b) = g(a \neq b) \land  g(b) \neq$ UNDEF).

Comment: Sorry, I had to change the definition but the edit window had run out. So I reposted an altered comment, but I hadn't seen that your reply yet.

Comment: "It only depends on on $f(b)$ in a neighborhood of a when $b\neq a$." When you put it like that, I start thinking about infinitesimals. Something like: $\lim_{b \rightarrow a} f(a) = L \iff f(a) \approx L$ when $b - a = \frac{1}{\infty}$.  So basically, if $\frac{b^2 - a^2}{b-a}$ is approximately $2a$ when there's an infinitesimal difference between $b$ and $a$, then we say it equals $2a$ at $b = a$, despite the zeros and whatnot. In other words, if the approach is consistent up to the point of infinitesimal difference, then we say it is correct when there is no difference.

Comment: @user110391 It's not an if and only if. More like $b \approx a \Rightarrow f(b)\approx L.$  Intuitively, it might be useful to say that $\frac{b^2-a^2}{b-a}$ is equal to $2a$ when $b=a$, but speaking formally it is not defined at $b=a$. It does not need to be defined there for the limit to exist. And again, I think you mean $\lim_{b\to a} f(b)$, not $\lim_{b\to a} f(a).$

Comment: [1/2] Your comments are noted. As for the fact that it isn't formally defined at $b = a$; is the correct thinking that the limit, as the name suggest, is the value that the expression's evaluation never exceeds/drops below after a certain point? As in, the $y$-values eventually collapse into a steady approach towards this limit, and once they've begun this part of the approach, they will never exceed/drop below that limit?

Comment: [2/2] This is how I've usually thought of the limit, but the problem is that just because a function's outputs has a limit as some input approaches a value, doesn't logically, to me, mean the function evaluates to that cap when the input has reached that value. Thus, the equation symbol is incorrect, no? Perhaps the limit function is not stating that the function $= L$ when $b = a$, but that it will always approach $L$ as $b$ approaches $a$. Whether it becomes $L$ when $b = a$ is irrelevant, because the limit function's statement is concerned only with what's true during the approach.

Comment: @user110391 I think approaches is a better word than exceeds or drops below. The basic idea is that if $\lim_{b\to a}f(b)=L$ then, no matter what degree of precision you require from the approximation $f(b)\approx L$, we can achieve that degree of precision by requiring $b$ to be sufficiently close to $a$. How close is sufficiently close depends on the degree of precision that you require for the approximation $f(b) \approx L.$ You are right that the limit of values $f(b)$ as $b$ approaches $a$ is not necessarily $f(a),$ unless $f$ is continuous. Your last two sentences are correct.

Comment: "Your last two sentences are correct." Then I think I've got it, thanks! I'll definitely have to continue thinking about it in order to reconcile it fully with my framework of math and logic, but it's all a lot clearer now.